# I need help on regular expression to allow number with character

Tags: java, regex

condition:

```
123           not valid
123 A         valid
abc123        valid
abc123Ab      valid
```

I have to apply regular expression compulsory character with number?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: You can use an online tool to implement test your regex, like: https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This will match any string starting with an optional set of digits followed by a combination of white spaces, letters and digits. But it still matches `123_` (that's `123 followed by a space` `)

```
^\d*[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

The following will check if you have at least one letter in your string combined with optional digits, white spaces and letters.

```
[a-zA-Z\s\d]*[a-zA-Z]+?[a-zA-Z\s\d]*
```

- `[a-zA-Z\s\d]` match a single character present in `[]`.
- Quantifier `*` : Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- Quantifier: `+?` Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

Answer (score 0):

```
(([a-zA-Z\s])*(\d{1,})([a-zA-Z\s]){1,}|([a-zA-Z\s]){1,}(\d{1,})([a-zA-Z\s])*)
```

first part of this expression will ensure string can start without any letters but atleast 1 digit must be present and should end with 1 or many letters. second part will ensure string can start with atleast 1 letter followed by atleast 1 digit and then followed by 0 or any number of letters.